# 2 form na mesma pagina com Spring mvc, Thymeleaf, alguém sabe como?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Essa tela de cadastro de Médico, dai criei esse modal pra o usuário poder cadastrar especialidades.

```
@GetMapping("/cadastro")
public ModelAndView preSalvar(@ModelAttribute("medico") Medico medico,@ModelAttribute Especialidade especialidade){
    return new ModelAndView("home","conteudo","medico/add");
}
```

Adicionei @ModelAttribute da especialidade, e o form de especialidade com th:object="${especialidade}" , mas está dando essa excessão : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'especialidade' available as request attribute

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já fez algo parecido?

Comment: A excessão se dar quando clico em cadastrar no form do médico

Comment: Acredito que a abordagem mais correta seria separar em dois forms: um para página principal e outro para o modal.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, acredito que o erro referido é pelo fato de você não ter colocado no @ModelAttribute o nome do objeto ao qual se refere e que está na view. Teste isso:

```
@GetMapping("/cadastro")
public ModelAndView preSalvar(@ModelAttribute("medico") Medico medico, @ModelAttribute("especialidade") Especialidade especialidade){
    return new ModelAndView("home","conteudo","medico/add");
}
```